# Auto-implemented property and remove its backing field

Tags: c#

I have a windows application where in the code is something similar.

```
public class Car
{
  private string _make;
  public string Make 
  {
    get { return _make; }
    set { _make = value; }
  }
}
```

I know that is old way of writing and this can be changed as below.

```
public class Car
{
  public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

But,I have few methods in Car class which uses _make variable, something similar as below.

```
public void SomeMethod1()
{
    _make = "Somevalue";
}

public void SomeMethod2()
{
   if (_make == "Somevalue")
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Now my question is , if I change it to the new way, how do I change _make variable in the methods which is using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all `_make` with `Make`. Use "Replace all" feature of visual studio (Ctrl+H).

You can do it another way. I do that a lot when I am in need of doing something similar.

- Remove the `Make` auto property temporarily, but leave the `_make` field.
- Then rename `_make` to `Make`. Wait for VS to show up that bulb, or do a `Ctrl+.` to bring up that menu with rename all option. Click that rename all option. Now all your `_make` has been renamed to `Make`.
- Finally convert `Make` into an auto property.